# guest OS can not connect to local site in vmware but can not connect to internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, vpn, vmware

I connect to internet via VPN connection in our university, First I connect to wireless access point after that I have an access to our university web site I mean I can connect to local web server after that I inter my username and password on VPN connection And finally I have Internet access. 
I have vmware and my guest OS is Ubuntu I set my connection to Bridge and I congig eth0 to to get ip automatically by its own DHCP, BUT in Ubuntu's firefox I have access just to our university web site  and I do not have access to internet. I search On this web site and I saw some solutions for times we do not use VPN!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you set your connection to bridge and you use vpn to access internet on your host.you should do this 1.disconnect your host vpn 2.use vpn on your guest after that u have access to internet but if you do not set vpn in your guest you just have access to your local web server and becouse ypu do not set vpn on your guest you do not have accesss to internet